# Annotations help in java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, annotations

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path()
public interface IDriver {


    public String GetDriverByID(int id);

}
```

In this code `@Path` an error pops up telling "the annotation path must define the attribute value". When I click on resolve it does this `@Path(value="")`.

What should is the value ??
I am working in eclipse, and it is a maven project.

Comment: The value should be the actual path that's being handled, for example `/drivers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Path` Identifies the URI path that a resource class or class method will serve requests for.

In your example, if you set path to "**drivers**":

```
@Path("drivers")
public interface IDriver {

    @Get
    public String GetDriverByID(int id);

}
```

And the application path is **myapplication** and the application is deployed at *http://example.com/*, then GET requests for `http://example.com/myapplication/drivers` will be handled by the `GetDriverByID` method.

See [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want your customers to access service you must provide them a path that they can use :

For this service:

> @Path("/product")
>   public class ProductService

You can access it by http request :

> host:port/servicename/rest/product

The /rest/ part depends on the web xml configuration (web.xml).